# I want to add a custom icons in the bottom tabs in tab navigation in react native

Tags: react-native

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

I am importing two files

```
import Profile      from './app/profile'
import Home     from './app/result'
```

Creating a bottom tab navigation which works but i just need to show custom icons where i can actually provide the icon path.

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator
({
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Profile:   { screen: Profile }
},

{
    initialRouteName: 'Discovery',
});
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this one. This is a snippet of my code.

```
ShoutOut: {
      screen:ShoutOut,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'ShoutOut',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, activeTintColor}) => (
           <Icon name="ios-megaphone" size={30} color={tintColor} />
           )
      },
    },
```

For your one should be...

```
    export default createBottomTabNavigator
    ({
        Home: { 
          screen: Home,
          navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, activeTintColor}) => (
                   <Icon name="home" size={30} color={tintColor} />
                   )
              },
        },
        Profile:   { 
          screen: Profile,
          navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
                tabBarIcon: ({tintColor, activeTintColor}) => (
                   <Icon name="user" size={30} color={tintColor} />
                   )
              }, 
     }
},

{
    initialRouteName: 'Discovery',
    tabBarOptions: {
       activeTintColor: '#fb9800',
       inactiveTintColor: '#7e7b7b',
       showIcon: true,
       style: { height: 54,backgroundColor: '#fff',borderTopWidth:0.5,borderTopColor: '#fb9800' },
       showLabel: true,
       labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 10,

       }
      }

});
```

Comment: ReferenceError: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Icon     Any idea where from i can import icon....

Comment: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons
You can use this one
Note: If you are using react-native init you need to react-native link

Comment: Thanks for that. I have included vector-icons. However, it was mentioned use Icons but that did not work. However FontAwesome worked for me. Thanks again.